# Generalizing the coin toss

Tags: probability-distributions, dice

So I was learning about coin/die tossing in classes and that got me thinking about something. If we take k n-sided die then the total number of outcomes is n^k. But that assumes that order matters (each roll is significant). How do we figure out the number of significant outcomes.

For eg. in a 6 sided die rolled twice: (1,2) and (2,1) are the same and only should count as a significant roll. For k=2, I've determined that the number is n(n+1)/2

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what benefit do you gain by equating $(1,2)$ with $(2,1)$? There is a study of such arrangements (where order doesn't matter), but it doesn't have much to do with rolling dice.

Comment: I was just curious what would happen if we took that as an assumption

Comment: As long as it's just curiosity about how many outcomes are actually different that way, and you don't use this number to calculate any probability of any kind, I suppose you'll be OK. The fact that you put "dice" and "probability distributions" in the tags for a non-probabilistic combinatorics question was just a little concerning, that's all.

Comment: Ahh my bad. I was thinking in context of the distribution and the image I had in my mind was dice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you heard of stars and bars?  Each die would be represented by a star while the bars are separators.  Everything before the first bar is a 1, everything between the first and second bars is a 2, etc.  For example, $*|**||*|**|$ would represent one 1, two 2's, one 4, and two 5's.  We need n-1 bars to separate out n possibilities for each n-sided die and k stars for k dice.  The number of different outcomes is the number of ways we can choose the positions of k stars out of k+n-1 possible positions.  So the number of possible outcomes is $\binom{n+k-1}k$.

Comment: How do I implement it here?

Comment: @pasha Read the last 2 sentences.  If we have n outcomes for each die (presumably 1 through n), we need n-1 bars to separate 1 category from the next.  For k dice, we have k stars, so k+n-1 symbols in all.  And the number of ways to choose which k of those k+n-1 symbols are stars is $\binom{n+k-1}k$.  Note this is consistent with your result for k=2.

Comment: Got it. Thank you.